# Trouble installing cordova cli

Tags: node.js, cordova

I tried to install the cordova cli to use it for a phonegap app, I installed the required node.js version and git client. But when I enter the command "C:>npm install -g cordova", I get this error,                                        `npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phon
egap requires cordova@'2.7.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cord
ova,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 5.1.1
cordova@5.1.1 C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── cordova-lib@5.1.1 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.
2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.1.0, rc@0.5.2, dep-
graph@1.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, init-pa
ckage-json@1.7.0, d8@0.4.4, glob@4.0.6, elementtree@0.1.6, request@2.47.0, cordo
va-registry-mapper@1.1.8, tar@1.0.2, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@4.0.0, cordova-app-
hello-world@3.9.0, npm@1.3.4)`

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a warning. Cordova should be installed, anyway.
Try reinstall again.
Before that clean the cache:

```
npm cache clean
```

remove cordova

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
```

maybe update the npm package manager:

```
npm install -g npm
```

and reinstall cordova again:

```
npm install -g cordova
```